# Login function OpenCart

Tags: php, authentication, opencart

I am building a web export from our program to OpenCart. I am working on the login function.

If you know which function I can use or where I can find them, then I would like to hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opencart version 2.3:

This controller file is responsible for admin login form:

```
admin/controller/common/login.php
```

And this file, controls admin users:

```
system/library/cart/user.php
```